# How to match a pattern but exclude from the result

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

Using the IIS URL Rewrite Module I am trying rewrite an incoming Url from **/en/page.aspx** to **/en/page/index.aspx**

Using regular expression I am checking that the string ends with .aspx

```
^.*(.aspx)$
```

Currently in capture group  I am getting

```
/en/page.aspx
```

How can i only capture **/en/page** part?

Further down the line I will rewrite the Url as follows:

```
{R:0}/index.aspx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match without capturing you can use the `?:` pattern, like `(?:\.aspx)`. However, to suit your redirection needs you may want to use the following expression:

```
^(.*)(\.aspx)$
```

So that `{R:1}` will point to exactly what you need. Also note you need to escape the dot, so that the expression will match the dot character and not every other one.

Answer (score 1):

Change how you capture matches...

```
^(.*?)(\.aspx)$
```

When going through the matches collection, the matches should be the following:

*index 0 should be the whole url*

*index 1 should be /en/page*

*index 2 should be .aspx*

Comment: What is the diff between ^(.*?)(\.aspx)$ and ^(.*)(\.aspx)$ ?  Specifically what does (.*?) do?

Comment: The question mark means that the star is lazy and won't match if the next character matches the next part of the expression.

Comment: `.*?` means non-greedy, which has no effect in this case because its followed by a plain string that's followed by `$` (which means end of string).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Given it to the Efan since he got there first :)